# Numbered hierarchical headings & lists in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

I'm helping my fiancé clean up some MS Word documents with a structure something like...

`<example>`

## 1. Level 1 Heading

Paragraph text.

Paragraph text.

## 2. Level 1 Heading

Paragraph text.

### 2.1. Level 2 Heading

Paragraph text.

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item

### 2.2. Level 2 Heading

Paragraph text.

- List item
- List item
- List item

## 3. Level 1 Heading

Paragraph text.

### 3.1. Level 2 Heading

Paragraph text.

#### 3.1.1. Level 3 Heading

Paragraph text.

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item

Paragraph text.

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item

#### 3.1.2. Level 3 Heading

Paragraph text.

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item

`</example>`

As I'm trying to do it, those hierarchical headings should be automatically numbered, & the numbered lists should be independent of the numbering of the headings.

I can do this easily in Apple's Pages, but am finding it impossible in Word. What happens is the numbered lists continue from the numbering of the heading above, then the heading below inherits from the last item of a list.

Advice needed.

Comment: For the Headings you have to use the heading styles, for the numbered lists use a list style . You find excellent tutorials here: https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html and here: https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html - they are old but still the way to go

Comment: @Ike I'm using defined styles for both but automatic numbering doesn't seem as well behaved as in Pages.

Comment: I don't know Pages - but in the links I provided all the pitfalls are described very well.